# $\left\lbrace{s_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ is convergent on $R^n$, with ${s_{k}}\rightarrow \langle a,b\rangle$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\lbrace{a_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ and $\left\lbrace{b_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ two convergent sequences in ${R}^n$, with ${a_{k}}\rightarrow a$ and ${b_{k}}\rightarrow b$. Let  $s_{k}:=\langle a_{k},b_{k}\rangle$ $\forall_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$. Show that the sequence $\left\lbrace{s_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ is convergent on $R$, with ${s_{k}}\rightarrow  \langle a,b\rangle$.

I think they are using scalar product, but I don't know how to apply that definition to sequences, any idea is very helpful, thanks

Comment: Is $\langle -,-\rangle$ an inner product? In that case, $s_k$ should be a sequence in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much it was a mistake, I already corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $k \in\mathbb N$, you have :
\begin{align}
|\langle a_k,b_k \rangle - \langle a,b\rangle|&\leq |\langle a_k, b_k - b\rangle| + |\langle a_k-a,b\rangle|
\end{align}

Since $(a_k)$ is convergent, it is bounded. Let $M>0$ be such that $\forall k\in\mathbb N, \| a_k\| \leq M$

Then, the Cauchy-Schwartz equation gives :
$$|\langle a_k,b_k \rangle - \langle a,b\rangle| \leq M \|b_k - b\| + \| a_k - a\| \|b\|$$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \langle a_k,b_k\rangle =  \langle a,b\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @TatianaMalespínAlvarado If this answered the question for you,  you should mark the "answered" check box to accept it.  This both marks the question as answered in the system as well as awarding some reputation for the person who wrote it.